# How to better understand a programme or languages documentation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to be more independent when learning code by referring to the language documentation a lot more. However whilst I might understand the extract of code that I am supposed to be learning, I often have difficulty understanding where in my project files it would go.

For example, recently I've been trying to implement the Firebase Realtime Database feature into my project, and have been consulting the official documentation to learn how to read and write data on iOS using the database. This is the segment I have been going through: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write .

This is where I have the issue, as the first section asks me to create an instance of FIRDatabaseReference, but I have no idea which of my project files or even where in it I am supposed to add this reference to.

I am not looking for an answer to that specific question - although it would be helpful - I'm more looking at what knowledge I am missing which would have helped me understand where that reference is supposed to go. I have attached a photo of my project files for convenience.

[!Project Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwj5W.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwj5W.png)

Comment: This question only makes sense if some of the getting started guide was skipped. For example in the [Installation and setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) section, it clearly states *Import the Firebase module in your UIApplicationDelegate subclass:* then text about how that would look. In your screenshot, there's a file called AppDelegate. Then, investigating the [Sample Firebase Apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/) would show mode details about where things are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach is to look at the code in the documentation to see what commands I don't understand. From your example, I did not understand "FIRDatabase", so I went on Google and found the following link, which provides detail on creating an instance:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase

Generally speaking, decomposing things to the lowest common denominator is a good start. From there, you can get into the more complex components, in your example, permissions, and so forth.